# Mongoose Model - Updating an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{ _id: 55c02ab7684c7a601ca24898,
  title: 'this is a better poll',
  link: 'this-is-a-better-poll',
  creator: 'user',
  __v: 0,
  choices:
   [ { text: 'Option 1', votes: 0 },
     { text: 'Option 2', votes: 0 } ] }
```

This is an example of a poll. Let's say I have multiple of these in my database.

I need to update the ***number of votes*** per POST request by the client by comparing the ***Option*** being posted to the server and comparing it to the database.

Since there are multiple polls in the database, I am using the ***link*** to find the exact database object.

I tried multiple ways to *update the votes count*, but nothing seems to work, changing the title works flawlessly though. Why?

Method that failed:

```
for example selection is: 
var selection = 'Option 1';
var link = 'this-is-a-better-poll';

1) Model.where({"choices.text": selection}).update({$set: {"choices.votes" : 1}});

2) Model.update({"choices.text": selection}, {'$set': {"choices.$.votes" : 1}});

3)     Model.findOne({
        link: link
    }, function(err, found) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Error'
            });
        }
        if (found) {
            console.log(found.choices);
            var arr = found.choices;
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i].text == selection) {
                    arr[i].votes = 1
                    console.log(arr[i].votes = 1);
                }
                found.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) res.send(err);
                    res.status(200).send({
                        message: 'Succes'
                    });
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

How can I solve this problem? How can I update the vote count when the selection is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection 2 should work perfectly with small changes:

```js
Model.update(
   {
       "_id": "55c02ab7684c7a601ca24898",
       "choices.text": selection
   }, 
   { "$inc": { "choices.$.votes" : 1 } },
   function(err,numAffected) {

   }
);
```

Where [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) is what you likely really want to do in order to "increase" the vote count of the matched option.

The other part there is the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator, which works with taking the element fromthe query selection `"choices.text"` where it matches the array index and "passing" that to the "update" block of the statment to update the matched index.

Also note that in the "query" block we are asking for the document `_id` value as well. It is likely that text like "Option 1" exists in many documents, so you really only want to vote on one of them.

Also the "positional" operator mentioned earlier only ever matches "one" array position per document. So if there are multiple occurances of "Option 1" then only the "first" match is ever updated.

If you need to update "more than one", then you are doing repeated operations until the numberAffected returns as `0` or whatever other approach you wish to use there. But only one will ever match and update per operation.

So **1.)** does not work because of the missing positional operator. And also **2.)** despite other problems is also very bad since it invoves reading the data and making the modifications in code, then "hoping" that nothing else changed the data before writing back to the server.

Apart from those problems with **2** alone, it is also multiple  requests to the server when you could just make only one.

Comment: that is a very detailed answer. So do you think it would be a better idea to add a new key in my Schema such as a (votted key), rather than nesting inside choices? I then add all votted options into the votted key, and do a client side array match and length to calculate the number of votes. Is that better? Since after all the number of votes only needs to be displayed on client side.

Comment: @cusX Cannot really tell what it is that you really want without more information. The best place to ask of course is with a new question, where you can explain the case you want answers for.